# What does it mean that we can attach numbers and words to concepts like age, name and length?

Tags: properties

When we talk about someones age and name we use "value" like words. The person's name is "John", it's length is "100m"...

What does that mean the for those concepts, do all these share a common property like "valued" or "numerical"?

Comment: You could think of it that way, but I don't see how that would be useful.

Comment: In computer programming that's just a name/value mapping. It's common for an object, a customer, say, or a product, or an invoice, or whatever it is you're keeping track of, to have a set of attributes presented as name/value pairs. Name=Fred, Height=5'11", Eyes=two, etc. Sometimes you can specify a type for the value, so Name must be assigned an alphabetic string, and Age has to be an integer greater than 0, etc. This isn't all that significant, it falls under the general topic of data processing or formal representation of data. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_model for example.

Comment: See the relation between universals and particulars...

Comment: @RichardBamdford What do you mean? Like what a valued property is, what it means for the object to have valued properties, how having valued properties can be used for comparison? Whether a set of valued properties describes the object? Whether sets with the same valued properties are identical? I mean there's a lot you can do with that.

Comment: @haxor789 Hi thanks, yeah exactly the first, what is a valued property? How can they have values and do they all have values? The apple is red but if we went and measured it it would be some sort of HSV or RGB value like 255,0,0.

Comment: It means the property can be put in one-to-one correspondence to another property that can be counted or indexed.

Answer (score 1):

I scan down the questions and finally find one that a physics type like myself can answer. I am gratified.

Names are simply symbols that are assigned. We assign them for convenience and according to taste. This happens within the context of culture and society such that certain names are well recieved while others are less so.

Names are useful in that we can refer to the object so named without having to point at it or describe it so as to be unambiguous. They do require some degree of cooperation to be useful. If I say "bring me a box of donuts" you must have had some previous experience to know what the words "box" and "donuts" mean.

Numerical values for things are quite different. These involve either counting or measurement. Note that the things do not have to be physical things, as the examples will show. They can be properties or even abstract concepts.

Mathematical consideration can produce numerical values. For example, the ratio of a circle's diameter to circumference is a numerical value. We give it the name pi. It is possible to calculate this value to arbitrary accuracy. There are many other examples.

Countining involves identifying each item in a group as a unit of a category. Thus, one person, one donut in a box of donuts, one car, one philosophical concept, etc. This is followed by counting those items to get the total.

Counting involves the difficulty of identifying correctly whether a subject item is in fact a member of the category, and whether it is in fact one whole unit without overlap of other items or a missing portion. Does that box of donuts contain the correct number of donuts? Are the items in the box donuts or have we been misled? Did we make a mistake counting those donuts? Is there a donut hidden behind the wax paper lining the box? Did somebody take a bite out of one donut? And so on.

Measurement means comparing with a standard. First we must identify a property that a thing has. Then we must identify a standard against which to measure that property. Then we must identify the ratio of the standard to the property of the subject item. Examples abound: Use a measuring cup to measure out 1 cup of milk. Use a tape measure to measure the width of a room. Use a clock to measure the passage of time from one event to another.

Measurement also has challenges. Have we in fact identified a useful standard? Is the standard one that applies to the property we are interested in? Is the comparison method a good comparison method? How accurate is the comparison?

A standard rule when using an object like a tape measure is: The uncertainty in the measurement is (at least) plus or minus half the smallest division on the tape. (If you are sloppy or if the measurement process is flawed in some way then the uncertainty may be larger still.) For example, suppose you have a tape that is divided down to 1 mm, and the result was 47 mm. Then any value between 46.5 mm and 47.5 mm could be the actual length of the object being measured.

Various measurement methods will give different accuracy estimates and be subject to systematic errors.

Counting and measurement thus share quite a bit. And have quite a bit of overlap in the difficulty in producing accurate results. There are also issues of such processes being repeatable, and being possible to be performed by different people and get equivalent results. (Equivalent in that the results from different attempts are within the uncertainty of eachother.)

Choosing a good standard is also crucial. It needs to be convenient to the measurement. It should be available to others for comparisons with their measurement efforts. And, it should not change over time.

To summarize: counting and measurement involve comparison to a standard in order to get the ratio of the subject item's property to the standard. And the numerical value thus produced will necessarily have some degree of uncertainty.

Answer (score 0):

A property or dimension can be:

- discrete   (like name, age)
- continuous  (like length)

Discrete properties/dimensions can be:

- categorical (like name, employer, hair color etc - **unordered** categories)
- numerical (so has an **order**)

Continuous dimensions are probably most of the time real numbers.

In other words, yes you can group properties under these classifications, and there exist words for these concepts.

Answer (score 0):

> How can they have values and do they all have values? The apple is red but if we went and measured it it would be some sort of HSV or RGB value like 255,0,0.

I mean the object itself only has a property, but value lies in the "eye of the beholder". So for example the human eye is only sensitive to electromagnetic radiation in the wavelength domain between 400-700 nm (which we call "light"). So things within that domain are visible to use and can be labeled with a quality red, green, blue etc or even with a quantity like if you mapped them on a rainbow from infrared to ultraviolet and assign numbers to them. The rest is not visible to us.

Similarly for the RGB value of an apple the "eye of the beholder" is simply a camera and a light detector. Like you open a window through which light falls in from all directions and you measure on a grid pattern where the light fell to and how much light got there. And if you split each grid in to segments with a red/green/blue filter (that only lets that pass and blocks the rest), then you've got yourself a representation of what you've measured and can later reverse the process.

So the apple emits/reflects light of a certain wavelength but how we call that and which numerical or linguistic name we make up for that is not a property of the apple.

Likewise not all objects have that property. Like something being really dark just absorbs so much light and emits so little that we just see it as dark. Whereas something that is so intense might just be seen as bright or if all sensors are maxed it's white. And some things are "invisible" to us. Now they do still have the property of emitting stuff, we just don't see it and therefore can't account for that.

And for example a "name" is more or less the sound sequence to which people respond. Which is more or less arbitrary. Now it has a "value" in the sense that it is "defined" for a person and not constantly changing but it's not like you can measure names. Although if you wanted to you could sort them by alphabetical order or stuff like that, but that's again not a property of the object but a quirk of the observer.

And last but not least the ordering of objects usually happens due to some preference of the observer.